# Beamer \institute text size change to small

Tags: beamer, fontsize, titles

I am using `beamer` with the `\institute` command.

I have several institutes and just want to change the font size of the institutes and not the whole document. I would like the institutes to be much smaller than the rest of the document.

Here is my code, but maybe I'm lost. Thanks for any input as I am new to `beamer` and LaTeX.

```
\institute[University of] {size=\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\selectfont University of Utah}%   
{
  \inst{1}%
  Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
  University of
  \and
  \inst{2}%
  Department of Chemistry\\
  University of
  \and
  \inst{3}%
  Department of\\
  University of
  \and
  \inst{4}%
  Department of \\
  University of
  ~ \\
  \pgfuseimage{medallion}
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can change the font size of `beamer` elements using `\setbeamerfont{<element>}{<font attributes>}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\tiny}

\institute[University of]{
  \inst{1}%
   Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
   University of
  \and
  \inst{2}%
  Department of Chemistry\\
 University of
   \and
  \inst{3}%
  Department of\\
  University of
  \and
  \inst{4}%
  Department of \\
   University of
  ~ \\
  \pgfuseimage{example-image}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you want to use absolute font sizes instead of the LaTeX commands `\tiny` ... `\Huge`, try something like

```
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}}
```

(`\selectfont` is not necessary in this context). Also see the [`beamer` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsubsection.18.3.3) for more information about `\setbeamerfont`.